# If $f(x)$ is defined on $x \in (a, b)$, then where is its integral, $F(x) = \int_c^x f(t) dt$, defined (for $c \in (a, b)$)?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, definition

One can argue that it is defined on $x \in [a, b]$, since one way to define an integral is:
$$
\int_c^x f(t) dt := \lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{f(x_i)}{n}
$$

where $x_i = c + \frac{(x-c)(2i-1)}{2n}$ for $i \in [n]$ (i.e. a midpoint Riemann sum)

and one can show that $\forall i \in [n]: f(x_i) \in (a, b)$ for any $x \in [a, b]$.

---

One can also argue that it is defined only on $x \in (a, b)$ by using the trapezoidal sum:

$$
\int_c^x f(t) dt := \lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{f(x_i)+f(x_{i+1})}{2n}
$$

where $x_i = c + \frac{(x-c)(i-1)}{n}$ for $i \in [n+1]$.

This definition fails when $x = a$ or $x = b$, since $f(x_{n+1})$ is not defined. So the integral must be defined on $x \in (a, b)$.

---

It is also possible to argue for $x \in (a, b]$ or $x \in [a, b)$ using left/right Riemann sums.

What interval should one use to formally define the integral function?

Comment: A simpler argument is to use $f(x) = \tan x$ on $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$, so that $F(x) = \ln|\sec x|$.

Comment: The integral of a function is unchanged if you change its values at finitely many points. So we can still talk about the integrability of $f$ on $[a,b]$; its values at the endpoints don't affect the integrability or the integral.

Comment: The symbol $\int_{c} ^{x} f\, dt$ can be defined only when $f$ is defined and bounded on the closed interval $[c, x] $ or $[x, c] $. If it's not the case then one must first ensure that this prerequisite is met. Thus based on your original question one can say that if $f$ is defined and bounded on $(a, b) $ then one can try to define $F$ on $(a, b) $. Whether the definition of $F$ will make sense or not depends on whether the function $f$ is integrable on the desired interval or not.

Comment: Also definition of integral via Riemann sum is not that simple as you seem to assume. You need to either vary the tags arbitrarily or vary the method of partitioning arbitrarily or both. Fixing the tags as well as partition (here division into intervals of equal length) does not give you the Riemann integral.